# Two-generated subgroup of a free group satisfying nontrivial relation

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I would like to use the following lemma.

**Let $F$ be a free group and let $X=\lbrace x,y \rbrace$, where $x,y \in F$. Put $G=\langle x,y \rangle$. If $G$ is not free over $X$, then $x$ and $y$ commute.**

I suppose it holds and I guess I could prove it using the Nielsen-Schreier theorem. However, the statement seems really trivial, so I suppose it must have been already formulated or there must be some more general theorem from which it immediately follows. On the other hand, I tried to google something like this and failed. So, could you please point me to some book/paper where it can be found or provide me with some nice proof (hopefully not much technical)?

Comment: By Nielsen-Shcreier, $G$ is a free group. If it is not free over $X$, then one of the element must suffice to generate the group, so $G$ is cyclic and thus abelian.

Comment: > If it is not free over $X$, then one of the element must suffice to generate the group... Could you please explain this step? The rest is clear.

Comment: It is a free group of rank 1 or 2.

Comment: I am aware of that. But why it cannot  be freely generated by some (other) two elements? Is there some general statement that if a free group of rank $n$ is generated by $n$ elements, it is always freely?